# SQL window function to choose one record vs another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query where I need to choose a record based on the following criteria:
 If PrimaryLocation = 'Y' then choose that record.  If PrimaryLocation  ='N' and locationstate = issuingstate, then choose the first record with matching states.  If PrimaryLocation = 'N' and issuingstate is NULL then choose the first record non NULL.  If PrimaryLocation = 'N' and all issuing states are NULL, then choose any record.

The dataset looks like this:

```
    ID      licensenumber     IssuingState       LocationName     PrimaryLocation  LocationState 
    10        555                FL                Coral             Y                   FL
    10        555                GA                Seaside           N                   FL
    20        777                FL                Jax               N                   FL
    20        777                FL                Broward           N                   FL
    30        999                FL                Broward           N                   GA
    30        999                FL                Davie             N                   FL
    40        888                NULL              Orange            N                   FL
    40        888                FL                Davie             N                   FL
    50        333                NULL              Dade              N                   FL
    50        333                NULL              Orange            N                   FL
```

For ID = 10 I would want just the first record, where PrimaryLocation = 'Y'.

For ID = 20 I would want either record.

For ID = 30 I would want the record with LocationName = 'Davie' since LocationState = IssuingState

For ID = 40 I would want LocationName = 'Davie' since Issuing State is not NULL.

For ID = 50 I could choose either record.

This dataset is part of a larger query where I'm using #temp tables.  I've been using Window Functions with Row_Number() but I'm having particular difficulty with the LocationState=IssuingState part of the query.

This is all I've been able to come up with so far:

```
    SELECT id, licensenumber, issuingstate, locationname, primarylocation, locationstate,
    DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY id, licensenumber, issuingstate
                     ORDER BY primarylocation DESC)
    INTO #LICENSES
    FROM TABLE

   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id, licensenumber, licensetypename, issuingstate,
                              ORDER BY PRIMARYLOCATION DESC) RN
   FROM #LICENSES
```

Comment: You are writing your query, where's your query?

Comment: you just wrote psudo-code for your WHERE clause.
Do that in a CASE statement in the where clause:

Comment: @Eric--I added the code I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can prioritize the conditions mentioned in `order by` in the `row_number` window function.

```
select * from (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by id order by 
                             case when PrimaryLocation ='Y' then 1 
                                  when PrimaryLocation ='N' and locationstate = issuingstate then 2
                                  when PrimaryLocation ='N' and issuingstate is NULL then 3
                                  else 4 end, locationName) as rnum
from tbl t
) t 
where rnum = 1
```

Comment: These are interesting answers.  I'm checking them now.

Comment: This seems to work.  Very simple explanation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the query is:

```
select *
from(
select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by id,issuingstate desc) as rn
from #temp
where (case when PrimaryLocation ='Y' then 1 
                when PrimaryLocation ='N' and locationstate = issuingstate then 1
                when PrimaryLocation ='N' and issuingstate is NULL then 1
                else 0 end) = 1
) a
where rn = 1
```